# Determine packets per second

Tags: linux, networking, ddos

What is an ideal way to get the number of packets per second on a Linux box?

Would I use tcpdump or are there better methods?

Comment: I feel like people downvoted this simply because the author used the word "ideal".  I still think it's a valid question - "How do I get the number of packets per second on a Linux box?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need an exact number then yes, I'd use that. but if it's roughly then you might want to look into [MRTG - Tobi Oetiker's MRTG - The Multi Router Traffic Grapher](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/).

Answer (score 1):

What do you need? Long term monitoring of packet statistics? Graphing? Further analysis?

If you just want to look at packet rates on a box, use [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/shots/iptraf-dstat1.gif).

Comment: Just to get an idea on a size of a ddos attack and the kind